# How to get clangd to use C++20

Tags: linux, emacs, llvm, clangd

When there is no other information, how can I get clangd to fallback to C++20?

This is on Arch Linux with a recent LLVM. This is run though the Emacs LSP, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 10):

You can add:

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c++20]
```

to a clangd config file. It can go in either a project config file (`.clangd` in a project directory) or to apply to all projects, a user config file (`clangd/config.yaml` in an OS-specific place).

For more details, see:

- https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#files
- https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#add

Comment: This doesn't b seem to handle to case where ther is no entry into the compilation database. eg, hasb't been a compilation since introduced. Can't use the compile flags alternate either because that blocks the compile database for the rest.

Comment: @JasonN As far as I know, `CompileFlags` should be respected even if there is no `compile_commands.json` present. To diagnose the issue further, could you share [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs)?

Comment: @HighCommander4 I’m pretty sure they mean the exact opposite: that the flag overrides the compilation database for every single file (e.g. C files also get parsed as C++20), while they only want to override it for unknown files

Comment: @AaronLiu Ah, I see. I don't know of a mechanism to restrict a config file entry to only apply to files with no compile command. However, it can be restricted to only apply to files with certain extensions (e.g. `.cpp` files but no `.c` files) using [`If`](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#if).

Comment: @AaronLiu There is also a protocol extension for the client to specify "fallback flags" in the `initialize` request (https://clangd.llvm.org/extensions#compilation-commands), but this requires client support. In vscode, it can be specified using the `clangd.fallbackFlags` vscode setting.

Comment: @FelixDombek your edit is slightly misleading: `.clangd` is only the file name for a project-level config file. For a user-level config file it's `clangd/config.yaml`.

Comment: @HighCommander4 You're right, I thought it was for both but it isn't. Maybe both names could be added to the answer?

Comment: @FelixDombek Sure, I expanded the answer a bit to cover that.