# Is there a way to specify the c++ standard of clangd without recompiling it?

Tags: c++, standards, clangd

I'm trying to use a feature in c++17(const lambdas) without having clangd error me. I've searched online and every answer tells me to recompile clangd with a flag. Is there truly no other way?

Edit: Clangd is not the compiler. It's a language server, which is a program made to be used with IDEs that basically checks your code for errors and warnings before compiling it. See https://clangd.llvm.org .

Comment: https://clangd.llvm.org/config#compileflags

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Read my question again, I believe it clearly states that I was asking for a solution that didn't require me to recompile clangd.

Comment: @AaronLiu did you read his link? It’s the correct answer to your question. Clangd accepts compiler flags to determine how to interpret the files.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73596097/141719) to a similar question. No recompiling clangd required, just creating a config file in the root directory of your project.

Comment: I read it but misinterpreted it. Sorry.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answer inspired by [n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m)

From https://clangd.llvm.org/config#compileflags:

You can create a config file for clangd. In the config file, you can specify the compiler options mimicked. For my question, do this:

```yaml
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c++20]
```

Put the configuration file as `.clangd` in a shared parent directory of the files you want this to apply to. If you want it to apply for the entire user, make it a `config.yaml` file in an OS-specific directory:

- *Windows*: `%LocalAppData%\clangd\config.yaml`, typically
  `C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\clangd\config.yaml`.
- *macOS*: `~/Library/Preferences/clangd/config.yaml`
- *Linux and others*: `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/clangd/config.yaml`, typically
  `~/.config/clangd/config.yaml`.

Comment: The config file is named `~/.clangd`. (ref: [*Configuration Files*](https://clangd.llvm.org/config#files))

Comment: This worked for me using the clangd Visual Studio Code extension as it just uses the machine's installation of clangd under the hood.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will also force c files to be treated as c++20 files, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: Is it possible to set the C++ version per project?

Comment: @FelixDombek @ynn’s path only works if your project file is under any `~/` or any subdirectory of it, as they’ve provided the way to specify it “per-project” for all subdirectories of `~/`. I’ve edited the answer.